# Backup script bash that reads a external config file

Tags: bash, arguments, backup

I have a **backup script** that reads from user input and compresses files and then tar.gz's them, but does anyone know the syntax to get a bash script to accept a argument from a file.

Eg

bash script is like

```
tar cvf /arg1
```

and in another `config.txt` file it would look like

#### enter location

```
/home/user/
```

And the usuage would be something like, backup.sh config.txt and i would pull the config locaion file and input it into the script and execute it.

Any ideas ?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have some code you can post? You can edit your question by clicking the [edit] link.

Answer (score 1):

```
tar cvf $(<"$1")
```

This will take the first argument from the command line, read its contents, and use those as the argument to `tar`.

Comment: Great, can i also add $2 etc for additional args ?

Comment: Try "$@" if you want to use all arguments.  I'm not sure if it will work directly here, or if you'll need to loop over the arguments.